# recycler view item decoration, getItemOffsets is only called on the last added item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

I have an item decoration attached to my recycler view. It should add a large amount of padding on only the last item. This works fine. However, as I add new items, `getItemOffsets` is called only for the last item (and not to every item in the recycler view`). This way, I end up with this large padding on every item.

How could I remove the right padding on the rest of the views when a new view is added? I want to add items the correct way to preserve animations

```
public void onItemInserted(Card card, int position){
    cardList.add(card);
    notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() -1);
}
```

My item offsets method:

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, State state) {
    super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
    outRect.top = horizontalSpace;
    outRect.bottom = horizontalSpace;
    outRect.left = horizontalSpace;
    outRect.right = 0;

    if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == parent.getChildCount() - 1){
       outRect.right = endSpace;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are adding one item but you want to re-draw all items. So, try to replace notifyItemInserted() by notifyDataSetChanged(). This will re-draw all items.

Comment: @W0rmH0le using notifyDataSetChanged loses the animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getItemOffsets()` is called for the last item only. So, decoration for old items won't ever be re-stored. This happens because you invoked: `notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() -1);`

In order to call the `getItemOffsets()` for the last two items, you must:

```
public void onItemInserted(){
    items++;
    int lastPosition = getItemCount() - 1;
    if(lastPosition > 0) {
        // Request to redraw last two items. So, new item will receive proper padding and old item will restore to the default position
        notifyItemRangeChanged(lastPosition - 1, lastPosition);
    } else {
        notifyItemChanged(lastPosition);
    }
}
```

Also, as yourself mentioned, you should use `state.getItemCount()` instead of `parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)` during `getItemOffsets()`

Comment: hmm tried both (second solution i guess is closer to what im after) but neither are working

Comment: so this is super helpful thank you, but this line outRect.left += mHorizontalSpace; isnt needed and has strange side effects, also this dies on rotation, ill try and expand on this and ill accept your answer many thanks

Comment: ok the actual answer for this is to use state.getItemCount() , many thanks i wouldnt have solved it without you

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use state.getItemCount() instead of parent.getChildCount()

Answer (score 0):

Try call RecyclerView.invalidateItemDecorations() before insert data.